# How to display Updated records in Gridview first row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am santhosha, actually am developing a sample web application using asp.net and c# which includes a sample CRUD operation, here i want to display updated record to first row of the gridview. I am new to Asp.net and C#, can anyone please get me out of this.

Advance Thanks.

With Regards,

Santhosha h P

Comment: Do you have any field in DB that would identify the recently added record like last_updated_date etc?

Comment: actually i dont hava any field for that

Answer (score 1):

use header template of gridview control to show updated record.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, can u please show me how to do that am new to this

Comment: have you know how to use tamplate in gridview ?

Comment: it seems that you are new to asp.net and GridView control. Any way for you it is better to read this frist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx#aspnett12ustmpfldsvb_topic1

Answer (score 0):

infact you can use header template, but i think you can maintain the last updated record flag /counter in database, and whenever you are updating the record just increment/update your counter or flag. and whenever you retrieving the records check the flag , and handle the Row_updating event where you can use item template. use item template and show the updated flag record.  in this way you can found the latest record at top of grid view.